# how Add multiple article id in Joomla header section

Tags: php, joomla

Joomla- how Add multiple article id

code here

```
<?php if (JRequest::getVar('view')=='article' && JRequest::getVar('id')==2) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by modifying your if statement to use PHP's [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) function and passing it an array of article IDs:

```
<?php if (JRequest::getVar('view')=='article' && 
          in_array(JRequest::getVar('id'), array(2,3,4,5))) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thannks, but its not working, please check it-anything missing?

Comment: What is the error you are getting back from PHP so I debug as the above sample is correct and complete?

Comment: i got another solution "|| JRequest::getVar('id')==22" now im ok, but i think your code is better unfortunately your code is not working

Comment: Sorry, looking at it again I have missed off the final closing bracket on the if statement. Please try it now.

Comment: Like you mention though you can of course use a logical or operator `||`, but you end up repeating yourself a lot! :)